# Javascript conditional execution and simplification

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, conditional-execution

I have the following script which works great however I think this can be simplify, right? also, I'd like it to trigger **only** once.

Example, user inputs "My Title". Script executes and user sees "my-title" in slug field. If user replaces title value by "My Crazy Title", I'd like the slug to remain "my-title". How?

```
$('#article_title').change(function() {
  str = $('#article_title').val();
  formatted = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  $('#article_slug').val(formatted);
});
```

See code example http://jsfiddle.net/TSrYu/

Comment: Not sure if this is valid, but you could try `$('#article_title').one( 'change', function(){} )`

Comment: Eeeck, please put `var` in front of `str` and `formatted` so they aren't implicit global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it this way:

1. Switch to using `.one()` to register your event handler so it only fires once.
2. Remove the intermediate variables and just process the string all at once

The code:

```
$('#article_title').one('change', function() {
    $('#article_slug').val($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase());
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XGjWA/

Answer (score 1):

```
var changed = false;
$('#article_title').change(function () {
    // do some other stuff
    if (!changed) {
        str = $(this).val();
        formatted = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        $('#article_slug').val(formatted);
    }
    changed = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/TSrYu/1/

Comment: Thanks @mohammad-adil I appreciate. it works fine. I chose the the solution below since it's shorter

Answer (score 0):

There are two minor improvements you can make:

- Not making your variables global by declaring them properly.
- Not querying the DOM again for the element, since it's already available by accessing `this`

To make sure it only happens once, you can unbind the event (last line in snippet

```
$('#article_title').change(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var formatted = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  $('#article_slug').val(formatted);
  $(this).unbind("change");
});
```